# crossfilter add record doesnt work when dimension with array filter is enabled

Tags: crossfilter

I've created a repl to show how to successfully add a record but seems to be overly complex.

```
const crossfilter = require('crossfilter2')

//Initial data
const data = [
  {id:1, tags:['a','b','c']},
  {id:2, tags:['a','e','f']},
  {id:3, tags:['m','n','o']},
  {id:4, tags:['p','n','d']}
  ]

//Mock updated object from server
const updatedObject = {
  id:2,tags:['a','n','o']
}

//Init crossfilter dataset
const cf = crossfilter(data)

// Add dimensions
let ids = cf.dimension(row=>row.id)
let tags = cf.dimension(row => { return row.tags 
}, true)


//First lets filter by dimension of arrays with value "a"
console.log('Filter by tag "A"')
tags.filter('a')

//From the chosen list we PUT the record to the server and get as response the mocked updatedObject with changed data
ids.filter(val=>{
 return val==updatedObject.id
})

/**
Starting from here this is the only way I've been able to successfully add the record
**/

tags.filter(null) //without this the the add() wont work as expected
console.log('Data before remove',cf.allFiltered())
cf.remove()
console.log('Data after remove',cf.allFiltered())

// We can remove the ids filter
ids.filter(null)
console.log('data without the removed record',cf.allFiltered())

// We can now add the new record
console.log('Add record to dataset')
cf.add([updatedObject])
console.log('With the new record',cf.allFiltered())
tags.filter('a')

/** We now have to reset the grouping with updated data **/

let tagGroup = tags.group() //We need to reset the grouping for the reduceCount to work as expected

console.log('The correct reduced count of tags',tagGroup.reduceCount().top(Infinity))

console.log('ALL RESULTS',cf.allFiltered())
```

[link to repl](https://repl.it/@anttima/cfDimensionWithArrays)

Can someone with a better understanding tell me if this is a use-case which wasnt thought of with the addition of `dimensions with array` or am I just missing something

All help appreciated

Comment: Yeah, I definitely think I'm seeing some weird behavior here, like records showing up in the counts but not being accessible with `allFiltered`, records getting counted twice, and so on. I've run out of time for the moment, hope to return to this later today. Until then, I think you are right, you do have to make sure that tag dimensions are not filtered when adding (and removing?) records.

Comment: coo, thanksl.. I've also posted an issue in the official github repo so lets see.

Comment: Yeah let's [continue the discussion there](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/issues/127#issuecomment-473847540).